# Unable to redirect to another page

Tags: php, html, redirect, post, header

I need help in resolving one of my issues based on the input data I am checking in the database. If value is present I am forwarding to another page; else an error shows.
Entering any value displays the same and I am unable to view echo with the php code. 
Testing the code by itself works fine, but when integrated with html code, it fails.
Can someone identify any mistakes in the code? How can I troubleshoot the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    include("connect.php");

    $message = NULL;
    if(empty($_POST["empid"])) {
        $u = FALSE;
        $message .= "You have to enter your Employee ID !<br />";
    }
    else {
        $u = intval(stripslashes(trim($_POST["empid"])));
    }

    if($u) {
        $query = "SELECT Emp_ID FROM Data  WHERE Emp_ID = '$u' ";
        $result = @mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row){
            session_start();
              header("Location: ModifyEmpInfo.php?empid=$u");

            exit();
        }
        else {
            $message .= "Employee ID provided does not exists. Try again!<br />";
        }
    }

}
$page_title = "FindEmpolyee";
if(empty($message)) {
    echo "<font color=red>So sorry, this page is only for Test members !</font>";
}
else {
    echo "<font color=red>";
    echo $message;
    echo "</font>";
}

?>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FindEmpInfo_files/form_init.js" id="form_init_script" data-name="">
    </script><link href="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery-ui-1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="FindEmpInfo_files/normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FindEmpInfo_files/default.css" id="theme">
    <title>
      FindEmpolyee
    </title>
  <script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery-ui-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery_002.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery_004.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/jquery_003.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/validation_data.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="FindEmpInfo_files/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>

  <body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"  method="post" style="WebkitTransform: " id="docContainer" class="fb-toplabel fb-100-item-column selected-object" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate" data-form="preview">
      <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d941d9; MIN-HEIGHT: 20px" id="fb-form-header1" class="fb-form-header">
        <a id="fb-link-logo1" class="fb-link-logo" href="" target="_blank"><img style="display: none;" id="fb-logo1" class="fb-logo" title="Alternative text" alt="Alternative text" src="FindEmpInfo_files/image_default.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="section1" class="section">
        <div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
          <div style="FILTER: " id="item1" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column">
            <div class="fb-header fb-item-alignment-center">
              <h2 style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: comic sans ms; COLOR: #249ee0; FONT-SIZE: 28px">
                Find Employee Information
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item3" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label style="DISPLAY: inline" id="item3_label_0">
                Enter Employee Id
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-number">
              <input id="item3_number_1" name="empid" min="0" max="999999999" step="1" data-hint="" autocomplete="off" required="" type="number" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["empid"])){echo $_POST["empid"];}?>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="fb-submit-button-div" class="fb-item-alignment-center">
        <input style="" id="fb-submit-button" class="fb-button-special" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit">
      </div>
    </form>


</body></html>
```

**Solution**: The issue was that the name was not sent to the php code.

Comment: Instead of `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` try `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`

Answer (score 6):

You can only use `header` before any output has been sent to the browser.

As soon as PHP encounters your `<!doctype>` line, it begins sending output to the browser, starting with the headers telling the browser that it is receiving "text/html". Once the headers are sent may no longer use `header` to modify them.

You'll need to move *all* your HTML, including the doctype, below your PHP code which redirects:

```
<?php
...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the redirect code before any non-PHP output on the page. Headers need to be sent before content. Right now you have a `doctype` before your PHP.

Basically, just make sure you aren't outputting any content to the browser (either by out-of-php text or by echo text or included content) before `header()` is called.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is put this code at the very top (before anything else!)

```
ob_start();
```

This will tell the server not to send the page until it has been entirely created and generated. Aside from letting you send headers in real time (a pretty nifty feature) it includes some performance advantages. You can read more about it at the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Additionally, with header() you must send the full http:// URL that you want the browser to redirect to, just like the Javascript window.location.

Comment: No. `ob_start` is the worst possible solution. It treats the symptom but not the problem. There is absolutely *no need* for output buffering here. The follwoing is a **bad thing**, not a feature you should desire: "This will tell the server not to send the page until it has been entirely created and generated." There are no performance advantages, only disadvantages.

Comment: There is rarely any absolute _need_ for output buffering, but there are potential performance advantages, and, as an extra benefit, it allows header() use. With ob_start, you can enable Gzipping which, unlike when executed with php.ini, you can selectively disable it for browsers without gzip enabled. Gzipping also can reduce the files size by roughly 50%.

Comment: There are no performance advantages, and it adds a layer of complexity where none is needed. And allowing you to write broken spaghetti code is not an "extra benefit". Your logic should precede HTML output, not be mixed in with it the way `ob_start` allows you to. Output buffering has valid uses. This is not one of them. Using it in this situation is an ugly hack.